# C# Jupyter Notebook

Tags: c#, jupyter-notebook

I hope no one will consider this question off topic. I am about to start exploring using the C# kernal in a Jupyter notebook. I see that there are several alternatives, some appear to be dated. I'm not really interested in exploring them all, I just want something that will work well enough for a demo. The purpose is evaluating this for teaching a post-secondary course in C# programming --- we are now using Visual Studio exclusively, and we feel the need for something a little more targeted and possibly amenable to some automation.

Question: Of the various alternatives available, which ones should I avoid? Which ones seem to have fewer problems using?

I currently use Jupyter for Python development, so at least I have some familiarity with the technology and can author a notebook.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this open source project [zabirauf/icsharp: C# kernel for Jupyter](https://github.com/zabirauf/icsharp). Which can be used in `Windows/MacOS/Linux`. Wish it be helpful for you.

Below is a video about `icsharp`:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tKYyjPCiKpM

[image]

Answer (score 3):

According to an [announcement](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-core-with-juypter-notebooks-is-here-preview-1/) on the 6th of November 2019...

> Try .NET has grown to support more interactive experiences across the web with runnable code snippets, interactive documentation generator for .NET core with dotnet try global tool, **and now .NET in Jupyter Notebooks.**

Details can be found in the provided link (https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-core-with-juypter-notebooks-is-here-preview-1/)

Answer (score 2):

Try this https://github.com/tlinnet/csharp-notebook

It's a Docker image with C# Kernel i Jupyter Notebooks and includes >200 Notebooks with C#. There is links to try online on mybinder.org